# How to add items/components programmatically to a layout of a widget in android studio?

Tags: android, android-layout, widget

Inside a non-widget layout you would have the next code to add some item:

```
// programmatically create the item
MyItem item = new Item(Context);
// get a layout defined in xml
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
rl.add(item); // add the programmatically created item
```

the problem is that in a widget we have only RemoteViews:

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.blabla)
```

Now views have the method addView which supports adding only other RemoteViews.

Is there a way for me to add the item dynamically inside a widget?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what type of component you want to add if you want to add small amount of control you can simply set it's visiblity and alter it with Java code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).